# How is it possible to have a UITabBarNavigationController with an un-selected tab?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I noticed the App Store has a feature to let the user know when internet connection is down, but navigating to a separate view controller, that has no Tab-Bar icon, and only contains a generic message to the user. Once the internet is back, the view is dismissed and the user is returned to the view they were accessing before.

How is it possible to push a view from a TabBar Nav.Controller, without having it own tab bar icon?

For demonstration, look at the image below:
[image]

Comment: Why do you have to "push a view from a TabBar Nav.Controller" ? In your example, when the internet connection is unavailable probably a new separate UIView is being added to the the view hierarchy. When the internet comes back, it it is removed the and the table view will display its data. What exactly do you want to do here ?

Comment: @pe60t0 , I know how to add a separate view to the existing controller. What I don't know is how to DE-SELECT the bar button at the bottom of the controller

Comment: I guess what you've shown above is implemented by changing the `selectedImage` property of the given `UITabBarButtonItem`.